# Chevy Cruze 2013-WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: smart-cars

Anyone knows if there's WiFi hotspot on the Chevy Cruze 2013? 
When I tried creating an account for OnStar it says I need to go to my dealership to upgrade my OnStar hardware...has anyone upgraded?

Comment: To be honest, I think you might get a better answer on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have a feeling it probably doesn't have one, given that a search for "hotspot" and "hot spot" yield nothing in the [owner's manual](https://my.chevrolet.com/content/dam/gmownercenter/gmna/dynamic/manuals/2013/chevrolet/cruze/2013_chevrolet_cruze_owners.pdf).